# cant pass date and time to next screen react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have this simple screen which contains date and time picker and I want to pass the value to next Screen as soon as I am pressing the button. How can i do this?

Here is the code:

```
<DatePicker
    date={this.props.date}
    mode="date"
    format="YYYY-MM-DD"
    minDate={todayDate}
    confirmBtnText="Confirm"
    cancelBtnText="Cancel"
    dateInput: {marginLeft: 36}
    onDateChange={(date) => this.props.dateChanged(date)}/>

<DatePicker
    date={this.props.time}
    mode="time"
    cancelBtnText="Cancel"
    dateInput: {marginLeft: 36}
    onDateChange={(time) => this.props.timeChanged(time) }
    {...otherProps}/>

<Button
    onPress={() => navigate(
        'Test',
        { text: this.props.navigation.state.params.text,
          name: this.props.navigation.state.params.name}
    )}>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 onDateChange={(time) => { this.props.timeChanged(time) }}
```

In onDateChange set the time value for state insteed of props use **this.setState({time:time})**
replace with 
`<Button onPress= {() => navigate('Test', { time: this.state.time })}>`
You can get the state value in next page props